# Iscsid not starting on a centos6 docker on MacOS host

Tags: docker, centos, containers, iscsi

I am trying to run iscsid on a centos docker. But the command fails with, "FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/4.9.13-moby/modules.dep: No such file or directory"

```
[root@7627d06541cc opt]# iscsiadm -m node -o new -T bilbo:cdisk0 -p 127.0.0.1
Starting iscsid: FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/4.9.13-moby/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/4.9.13-moby/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/4.9.13-moby/modules.dep: No such file or directory
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/4.9.13-moby/modules.dep: No such file or directory
                                                       [  OK  ]
iscsiadm: can not connect to iSCSI daemon (111)!
New iSCSI node [tcp:[hw=,ip=,net_if=,iscsi_if=default] 127.0.0.1,3260,-1 bilbo:cdisk0] added
```

Docker is being started using,

```
msingh$ docker run -it cent6 bash
```

Info Inside the docker

```
[root@7627d06541cc opt]# uname -a
Linux 7627d06541cc 4.9.13-moby #1 SMP Sat Mar 25 02:48:44 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@7627d06541cc opt]# ls /lib/modules/
2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64
```

I have also tried creating a soft link from

```
[root@7627d06541cc opt]# ln -s /lib/modules/2.6.32-642.13.1.el6.x86_64 /lib/modules/4.9.13-moby
```

However iscsid still fails with

```
[root@7627d06541cc opt]# iscsiadm -m node -o new -T bilbo:cdisk0 -p 127.0.0.1
Starting iscsid: FATAL: Error inserting iscsi_tcp (/lib/modules/4.9.13-moby/kernel/drivers/scsi/iscsi_tcp.ko): Invalid module format
FATAL: Error inserting ib_iser (/lib/modules/4.9.13-moby/kernel/drivers/infiniband/ulp/iser/ib_iser.ko): Invalid module format
FATAL: Error inserting cxgb3i (/lib/modules/4.9.13-moby/kernel/drivers/scsi/cxgbi/cxgb3i/cxgb3i.ko): Invalid module format
FATAL: Error inserting cxgb4i (/lib/modules/4.9.13-moby/kernel/drivers/scsi/cxgbi/cxgb4i/cxgb4i.ko): Invalid module format
FATAL: Error inserting bnx2i (/lib/modules/4.9.13-moby/kernel/drivers/scsi/bnx2i/bnx2i.ko): Invalid module format
FATAL: Error inserting be2iscsi (/lib/modules/4.9.13-moby/kernel/drivers/scsi/be2iscsi/be2iscsi.ko): Invalid module format
```

Answer (score 0):

--privileged should fix this issue. But, you should use --privileged only using docker run and not during docker build.

docker run  **--privileged** -d --name stack stack:latest